# Verificar si un metodo se ejecuto en dependencia del valor de retorno de otro metodo

Tags: .net

Con xUnit y Moq verificar si un metodo se ejecuta en dependencia del valor de retorno de otro metodo. Ejemplo:

```
public class A 
{
    public bool M1() { // return true or false ... }
    public void M2() { // Do something ..... }
}

public class B 
{
    private A objectA;

    public B(A a)
    {
        objectA = a;
    }

    public void Mb ()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            if (!objectA.M1())
                continue;
            objectA.M2();
       }
    }
}
```

Quiero verificar algo como esto:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<A> mockA = new Mock<A>();
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M1()).Return(true);
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M2());

    // Act
    B b = new B(mockA.object);
    b.Mb();

    // Assert
    mockA.Verify(m => m.M2(), """si M1 retorno true"""); // esto me resolveria si fuera posible algo como eso
}
```

Notar que si M1 retorna TRUE "n" veces M2 se ejecutaria exactamente "n" veces.
Es posible hacer esto con xUnit y Moq ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguien me ayudo con la respuesta que estaba buscando y es esta:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<A> mockA = new Mock<A>();
    int count = 0;
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M1()).Returns(true).Callback(() => { count++; });
    mockA.Setup(x => x.M2());

    // Act
    B b = new B(mockA.Object);
    b.Mb();

    // Assert
    mockA.Verify(m => m.M2(), Times.Exactly(count), "all exactly time that M1 returned false");
}
```